# Trying to combine two Select Case Functions into one For Loop argument

Tags: vb.net, excel

In my project I have 2 functions with 3 sheets each that I have set up as Select Case. Each function is divided into 3 sheets. These procedures are part of a larger program that imports data into an excel workbook and then it formats that data to perform some analytics. Thus, there is a step by step order that has to be followed when executing each sub.

The reason is because anything that happens to one sheet, must happen to the other 3 in the Function. For example, if one is sorted, then all 3 must be sorted. With that in mind, I have a procedure that autofills some data from B6:AH6 in the first Function with three sheets.

Here it is:

```
    Public Function EmployeeSheets(Index As Long) As Excel.Worksheet

    'This function indexes all of the Employee sheets
    'to use in various loops during he instal process
    '@param EmployeeSheets, are the sheets to index

    Select Case Index

        Case 1 : Return xlWSAllEEAnnul
        Case 2 : Return xlWSAllEEHourly
        Case 3 : Return xlWSAllEESalary

    End Select

    Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index")

End Function

Sub copyFormulas()

    Dim eeRefSheets As Excel.Worksheet

    For i As Long = 1 To 3 Step 1

        eeRefSheets = EmployeeSheets(i)

        With eeRefSheets
            Dim lngLr As Long

            lngLr = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows).Row

            .Range("B6:AH6").AutoFill(.Range("B6:AH" & lngLr), Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillDefault)

        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

So no problem there, all works well. Except that now I have to do the exact same thing to these sheets:

```
Public Function PositionSheets(Index As Long) As Excel.Worksheet

'This function indexes all of the Position sheets
'to use in various loops during he instal process
'@param PositionSheets, are the sheets to index

Select Case Index

    Case 1 : Return xlWSAllPositionAnnul
    Case 2 : Return xlWSAllPositionHourly
    Case 3 : Return xlWSAllPositionSalary

End Select

Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index")
```

What I would like to do is to instead of writing my For Loop twice, combine both Select Case index into one loop and perform the autofill.

Can this be done, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make it as a sub .. and use Byref as variable reference ..

```
Public Sub EmplNPosSheets(Index As Long, ByRef ES As Excel.Worksheet, ByRef PS As Excel.Worksheet) 

    'This function indexes all of the Employee sheets
    'to use in various loops during he instal process
    '@param EmployeeSheets, are the sheets to index

    Select Case Index

        Case 1 
          ES = xlWSAllEEAnnul
          PS = xlWSAllPositionAnnul
        Case 2 
          ES = xlWSAllEEHourly
          PS = xlWSAllPositionHourly
        Case 3 
          ES = xlWSAllEESalary
          PS = xlWSAllPositionSalary

    End Select

    Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index")

End Sub
```

To use it, do like this ..

```
Dim eeRefSheets As Excel.Worksheet 
Dim posRefSheets As Excel.Worksheet

Set eeRefSheets = Application.Worksheets(0)
Set posRefSheets = Application.Worksheets(0)

EmplNPosSheets(i,eeRefSheets,posRefSheets)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the sub and tried to use: EmplNPosSheets(i,eeRefSheets,posRefSheets). But is telling that eeRefSheets and posRefSheets are passed by reference before it has been assigned a value.

Comment: @JoseM. .. you may assign it with dummy value .. it's updated